# Haskell type mismatch

Tags: haskell

I have the following functions:

```
encodeChar :: Int -> [Char] -> Char -> Char
encodeChar x y z = eChar (offsetChar x y) z

encodeString :: Int -> [Char] -> String -> String
encodeString _ _ "" = ""
encodeString x y z = encodeChar x y (head z) ++ encodeString x y (tail z)
```

Which returns

```
*** Expression     : encodeChar x y (head z) ++ encodeString x y (tail z)
*** Term           : encodeChar x y (head z)
*** Type           : Char
*** Does not match : [Char]
```

However, as x and y match Int and [Char] and (head z) returns type Char I don't see what is causing the problem... Ideas? :S Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`encodeChar` returns a `Char`, yet the first argument to `++` here needs to be a `[Char]`.  Use `:` instead of `++`.

Comment: Aaah of course :S Hehe sorry, I keep forgetting that the functions can generate list and try concatenating everything as if it were a string, thanks, works! :D